# Indexing Multiple Lists in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, indexing

Is it possible to index lists multiple times?

The situation here is I want to be able to change which list is presented based on the date. For simplicity I have given int day a val of 2 to try to get the second list. My issue is with the Binding context -> **BindingContext = TrainingDay[ndx1],[ndx];** (list name + number + indexed line in the list)... Obviously this is wrong, but how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
public partial class TESTPAGE : ContentPage
{
    static int day = 2;
    List<TrainingDay1> TrainingDay1 { get; set; }
    List<TrainingDay2> TrainingDay2 { get; set; }
    int ndx = 0;
    int ndx1 = day;
    private int _countSeconds = 4;

    public TESTPAGE()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TrainingDay1 = new List<TrainingDay1>
        {
            new TrainingDay1
            {
                EngText = "Day 1"
            },
            new TrainingDay1
            {
                EngText = "Day 1 again"
            }
        };

        TrainingDay2 = new List<TrainingDay2>
        {
            new TrainingDay2
            {
                EngText = "Day 2"
            },
            new TrainingDay2
            {
                EngText = "Day 2 again"
            }
        };

        BindingContext = TrainingDay[ndx1],[ndx];

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            _countSeconds--;

            if (_countSeconds == 0)
            {
                ndx++;
                _countSeconds = 3;
            };

            CountLabel.Text = _countSeconds.ToString();
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it would probably be easier to have two separate ListViews and simply toggle their visibility so only one is shown at a time

Comment: Its hard to talk clearly about the situation, given that you use `TrainingDay1` both as the class name of an item, and as the list name. Changing the names slightly, create lists `List<TrainingDay1> TrainingDays1` and `List<TrainingDay2> TrainingDays2`. Displayed by a `ListView` or `CollectionView`. If have `<CollectionView x:Name="theView">`, then do `theView.ItemsSource = TrainingDays1;` or `theView.ItemsSource = TrainingDays2;`.

Comment: `BindingContext = TrainingDay[ndx1],[ndx];`   Sorry,I don't quite understand this line of code.  What's the `TrainingDay` ? Can you elaborate on what you want to implement?

Comment: Jason's comment gave me the idea to set up an IF statement which works. If (day ==2) then BindingContext = TrainingDay2[ndx]